# What is an anonymous user capable of?

Tags: support, unregistered-users, anonymous

I know it's possible for someone to add an answer or improve a post (edit) without having actual account.

What else is an anonymous visitor or unregistered user capable of in Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Logging in to the site

Comment: From what I've seen so far, mostly what anonymous users are capable of is attempting to vandalize other people's posts. Considering how easily some reviewers approve terrible edits, as if they're not even looking and just trying to earn a cheap badge by clicking "Approve" all the time, I have no doubt that some of those vandalism attempts slip through.

Comment: @AdiInbar  There can even be collusion between the anonymite and the edit reviewer.  Someone anonymous vandalized a post I had on Skeptic Exchange, had to roll it back.  This was some time ago.

Comment: @user137487 In fact, since the anonymous user is, well, anonymous, one of the reviewers can be the same person who suggested the edit. All he has to do to cover his tracks is make his anonymous edit suggestion by proxy and change his browser's useragent. Then it only takes two reviewers sleeping on the job to get that vandalism approved. And from what I've seen so far, getting two out of four edit reviewers who are sleeping on the job isn't that rare.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on what anonymous users _are_?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just opened StackOverflow in Incognito mode to play around as an anonymous user. I've found that I can:

- Read questions, answers, help center pages and other site information
- View public information on user profiles
- Suggest an edit to a question
- Suggest an edit to an answer
- Answer a question
- Share a permalink to a question or answer
- Submit anonymous feedback
- Subscribe to the newsletter
- Login and/or sign up (obviously)

Feel free to add to this list if I've missed anything

Comment: Anonymous answers can also post questions on most sites, but it's disabled on some of the higher-trafficked ones like Stack Overflow.